# Problemas ao acessar pagina PHP via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Estou tendo problema ao acessar uma pagina PHP via ajax. Quando estou tentando acessar no access.log da o seguinte erro:

> "POST /eglise/mobile/MOB_Acao.php HTTP/1.1" 200 84 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT920 Build/3_190_2009) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"

No ajax estou fazendo assim:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: w_servidor+"/MOB_Acao.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function( data )
        {
            var e = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(e.codError == 506);
        }
 });
```

A minha variável w_servidor é `var w_servidor = "http://meuip:8080/eglise/mobile";`

Procurei sobre `htaccess` porém não tem nada haver com que está acontecendo. O projeto é `mobile`, e o que nos torna mais interessante é que no `mobile` funciona perfeitamente.

Esta requisição especificamente estou fazendo uma consulta, a pagina que recebe a requisição está escrita assim:

```
<?php

include "MOB_PessoasBanco_class.php";
$acao = $_POST['acao'];
error_log($acao);
if ($acao == 'verificar') {
    $actionExecute = new PessoasBanco($_POST, 'verificar');
    echo $actionExecute->verificarPessoas();
}

if ($acao == 'cadastrar') {
    $actionExecute = new PessoasBanco($_POST, 'cadastrar');
    echo $actionExecute->cadastrarPessoa();
}
```

A pagina que chamo a seguir faz a pesquisa no banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
$data = $this->conexao->fetchNaoRestritivo($sql, $dataInput);
```

Porém o problema não está nesta parte, pois quando abro do `IntelXDK` ele funciona perfeitamente, e até fiz outro projeto para testar esta conexão e tudo funcionou. Então o problema está no meu código, ou em outra parte do projeto.

Comment: a mensagem do seu access.log esta retornando ok, que tipo de dados que voce esta enviando para o servidor ?

Comment: Estou enviando codigo, email, e senha

Comment: para acessar meu banco de dados e fazer um teste.

Comment: Na real, ele não está nem acessando a minha pagina.

Comment: pelo que eu estou vendo voce esta querendo enviar dados de um formulario via post com ajax como e que voce esta recuperando esses dados voce esta inserindo ou consutando em banco de dados? de mais detalhes do problema

Comment: o uso do parse é usado em  `$.post()`, para `$.ajax({ })` , você deve informar o tipo: `dataType:'json'`, e qual é a estrutura de: dados ?

Comment: A principio não vi problema em termos de código. O que parece é que, você está fazendo a requisição corretamente, porém, não está conseguindo tratar o retorno. No código PHP tente retornar um array ou json e no datatype da requisição Ajax defina o tipo de dado de retorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa informação no access log diz que a requisição retornou o status 200 (Ok). Não é um erro. O problema, como o Ivan falou, é que com `$.ajax()` você não deve usar `$.parseJSON()`. Você precisa especificar o tipo de retorno no parâmetro `dataType` do Ajax.

Ficaria assim:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: w_servidor+"/MOB_Acao.php",
            data: dados,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data )
            {
                // Data é o Array correspondente ao JSON retornado pelo webservice.

                //Você pode dar um console.log(data) para ver a estrutura do Array
            }
     });
```

Ah, se não for, monitore o envio da requisição no console, veja se vai retornar o status 200 mesmo. Se não retornar, comenta aqui o código retornado.